# Finding an element in a list of lists using recursion

Tags: python, arrays

Given the following array,

```
l = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
```

I am asked to define a recursive function that outputs `"yay"` every time we find a certain element in this 2D array.

---

```
def f(element, lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    if len(lst[0])==0:
        return f(element,lst[1:])
    if lst[0][0]==2:
        print("yay")
        return f(element,lst[0][1:])
    return f(element, lst[0][1:])

f(2, l)
```

I should be getting `"yay"` printed once. Instead I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finder.py", line 37, in <module>
    f(2, l)
  File "finder.py", line 35, in f
    return f(element, lst[0][1:])
  File "finder.py", line 30, in f
    if len(lst[0])==0:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Normally you can get the `len()` of a sublist, but not in the case where you check inside a function.

---

**How can I check for an element in a 2D list using recursion?**

Comment: @KenY-N: Even then it doesn't work and give the same error

Comment: I'm not sure what this implementation is really trying to do (perhaps explain the thinking behind it?) - but I can't actually think of a good way to do this using recursion. (The data structure has only 2 levels, and only one of those can actually contain the value 0.) I'd probably just do this in a loop instead.

Comment: I think `if isinstance(lst, list): return 0` is needed. Please also note we expect the actual code to be posted, so please correct the declaration.

Comment: Edited, now it is )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging, I usually find it very helpful to print out the values to see where they're erroring out. In this case (after fixing your assignment for `l` since you seemed to have copied it wrong):

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


def f(element, lst):
    print("Element: " + str(element))
    print("List: " + str(lst))
    if not lst:
        return 0
    if len(lst[0])==0:
        return f(element,lst[1:])
    if lst[0][0]==2:
        print("yay")
        return f(element,lst[0][1:])
    return f(element, lst[0][1:])

f(2, l)
```

Which leads to:

```
Element: 2
List: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Element: 2
List: [0, 0, 0, 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    f(2, l)
  File "test.py", line 18, in f
    return f(element, lst[0][1:])
  File "test.py", line 13, in f
    if len(lst[0])==0:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

It is erroring out on this line `if len(lst[0])==0:` because you're trying to take the `len()` of whatever object is in the 0th place of your list, which is a number.

As an example, this is almost exactly what is happening:

```
>>> len(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

@slybloty's answer is why you're only getting a list.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
return f(element,lst[0][1:])
```

`lst[0][1:]` cuts down your list of list into just a list. You get:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

That's why `len(lst[0])` fails because `lst[0] = 0`, an `int`, therefore you can't get `len()` from it.

You have to rethink your process.

### Part II:

What you're looking for will end up with a pretty ugly approach. Keep in mind you have to navigate both sides of your array. A nested loop can handle that nicely, unlike recursion.

Python has easier ways to do what you want, such as:

```
[print('yay') for i in l for j in i if j == element]
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration for your list really only creates one list of integers.

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 1, 1, 3, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Python assigns `l` to `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and doesn't care about the next 4 lines. Because of that, this line:

```
if len(lst[0])==0:
```

attempts to find the length of `l[0]`, which is an integer.

Simply change your declaration for `l` to this:

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: But the call stack indicates that the error is after one level of recursion and the OP has pointed out their typo.